# Creating relationship between 2 tables in CakePHP using models to write less code

Tags: php, cakephp, model, has-many, belongs-to

I try to say just CkMmUsersKta.user_id=CkSetupUser.id and define relationship between 2 tables in CakePhp. 
I defined models and called models in function in controller but says Undefined index for

```
$c['CkSetupUser']['user_name']
```

CakePHP's 
Notice (8): Undefined index: CkSetupUser [APP\Controller\RealsController.php, line 67]

my controller:

```
class RealsController extends AppController {

   public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
   public $uses =array('CkMmUsersKta','CkSetupUser');

  public function index(){
   $this>loadModel('CkMmUsersKta');$this>loadModel('CkSetupUser');

   ini_set('memory_limit', '2000M');

   $cs=$this->CkMmUsersKta->find("all",array('fields'=>array('CkMmUsersKta.id')));

      foreach($cs as $c):
        echo $c['CkMmUsersKta']['id'].$c['CkSetupUser']['user_name']."<br />";
      endforeach;
   set_time_limit(0); 
   }
}
```

my CkSetupUser model:

```
    public $hasMany = array(
        'CkMmUsersKta' => array(
            'className'     => 'CkMmUsersKta',
            'foreignKey'    => 'user_id',
            'dependent'     => true
        )

    );
```

my CkMmUsersKta model:

```
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'CkSetupUser' => array(
            'className'    => 'CkSetupUser',
            'foreignKey'    => 'user_id'
        )

    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are fetching only id field in:

$cs=$this->CkMmUsersKta->find("all",array('fields'=>array('CkMmUsersKta.id')));

You should specify the name field also.

**$cs=$this->CkMmUsersKta->find("all",array('fields'=>array('CkMmUsersKta.id','CkSetupUser.user_name')));**